# Convex combination "adjacency" matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to figure out how to create an "adjacency" matrix, except it relates two sets of points as the convex combinations of the original points to get the new points.

$$x' = Hx$$
$$x\in\mathbb{R}^n,~x'\in\mathbb{R}^m,~H\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$$
$$\sum H_i=1$$

and there are no more than 2 non-zero entries in each row. Since $x'$ and $x$ are known, one method is to loop over the entries of $x'$ and then $x$ to manually find the combinations, but this seems very naive. I looked at right-multiplying by the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse but since the system is underdetermined, the constraints on $H$ aren't satisfied.

What can I do to efficiently find $H$ to use down the line?

Comment: Given that only $x, x'$ are known, this problem seems to be underdetermined. In order to fully determine the convex combinations you would also need to have some knowledge of the actual connectivity of the graph (the actual adjacency matrix). If the adjacency matrix is known, then the combinations are determined uniquely, but if not there are multiple possible solutions. As stated, there exist (at most) $ m{n\choose 2}$ H matrices that solve the problem.